# Losing quality when converting View to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, kotlin, itext, bytearrayoutputstream

I am trying to convert views into Images and put them in a PDF file using iText. But I am losing quality. Is it related to `Bitmap.compress()` function?

```
 val screen = getBitmapFromView(
        context.window.findViewById(id))
    try {
      val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
      screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
      val image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray())
      image.alignment = Image.ALIGN_CENTER
      document.add(image)
}
```

My `getBitmapFromView()` function:

```
private fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
      val returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height,
          Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
      val canvas = Canvas(returnedBitmap)
      val bgDrawable = view.background
      if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas)
      else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
      view.draw(canvas)
      return returnedBitmap
    }
```

[image][image]

Edit: Added screenshots

Comment: Are you sure its the image that lost the quality and not the iText library that is changing the quality? I would bet its the library

Comment: @greenapps Edited.

Comment: PNG is lossless, so its not due to the compression.

Comment: @tyczj iText does not change image qualities. It does only embed images as they are into PDFs.

Comment: @SuperHaker that being said, can you show how you determined that you lost quality? E.g. by sharing a canvas screenshot and the resulting pdf? I would assume that this effectively is a case of inadequate expectations. The original canvas on screen by default is displayed at its native resolution but the image in the pdf might be zoomed a bit. Bitmaps with merely screen resolution can look pretty bad if displayed at a slightly changed resolution.

Comment: @tyczj I saved the image in storage before putting it in pdf and the quality is still bad

Comment: @mkl  Added screenshots. Is there any workaround to get high quality Bitmap from View. I read that using Bitmap.Config.RGBA_F16 instead of ARGB_8888 can be better but it is only available from API 26.

Comment: I honestly dont see a difference between the 2 images. You made it seem like they are unreadable but clearly they are not

Comment: I also merely see a small difference, and that difference can be easily explained as mentioned above: You effectively are showing an image at a resolution a bit smaller than its original one which causes interpolation artifacts to occur. That been said, your PDF is centered on textual content, and expectations concerning textual PDFs are that the text is not drawn using bitmaps but instead as actual text with vector graphics qualities. A resume PDF based on a bitmap makes a very bad impression to start with, one you can hardly make up with qualifications.